# Como crear base de datos sql en python

Tags: python, sql, odbc

Quisiera saber si es posible crear una base de datos desde python, ya que mi problema es el siguiente, para conectarme lo hago de esta manera..

```
import pyodbc 

server = 'ip'
database = 'db'
username = 'asd'
password = 'asd' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+
                      ';DATABASE='+database+
                      ';UID='+username+
                      ';PWD='+ password)
```

saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con omitir en la cadena de conexión el argumento `DATABASE` y crear la base de datos después del modo común:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+
                      ';UID='+username+
                      ';PWD='+ password)

cnxn.execute("CREATE DATABASE ?", db)
cnxn.execute("USE DATABASE ?", db)
```

Asegúrate que el usuario de conexión tiene permisos para crear bases de datos.